# "В" или "на" Адриатике?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, названия

Как правильно: "в Адриатике" или "на Адриатике"?

Answer (score 1):

Используются обе формы, но немного в разных ситуациях.

Когда речь идет о плавании на кораблях, о движении эскадры, о военных действиях на Адриатическом  море, то обычно говорят "в Адриатике".

Если же речь идет о большой территории, включающей Адриатическое море, а также государства, имеющие вдоль него береговую линию (курортные города, озера, горнолыжные центры и т.д.), то используется форма "на Адриатике".

Примеры

Сообщают, что союзный флот в Адриатике близ Корфу, задержав подозрительное судно, обнаружил 200 мин.

Живет она на Адриатике, у моря. Тебе все Рибас расскажет… [Эдвард Радзинский. Княжна Тараканова (1999)].

Я был не раз на Адриатике. И в Дубровнике, конечно.

Там прозвучали знаменитые слова о том, что от Штеттина на Балтике до Триеста на Адриатике на континент опустился железный занавес. [Владислав Быков, Ольга Деркач. Книга века (2000)].